# Creating JSON Objects from Relational DB JPA/Hibernate Queries

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a relational DB accessed with JPA/Hibernate in a Spring web app. I have a lot of Ajax queries where the relational results need to be translated into JSON objects. Is there a simple solution to convert something like this, from a Relational JPA query, to the below?

[image]

Result

```
[
  { id: event-..782, color: rgba(14,48,71,0.6), startTime : 2017-12-27 00:05, endTime: 2017-12-27 00:25 },
  { id: event-..801, color: rgba(249,115,0,0.6), startTime: 2017-12-27 00:30, endTime: 2017-12-27 00:45 },
  { id: event-..776, color: rgba(255,0,0,0.99), startTime: 2017-12-27 00:00, endTime: 2017-12-27 00:05 },  
  { id: event-..838, color: rgba(255,0,0,0.99), startTime: 2017-12-27 00:25, endTime: 2017-12-27 00:30 }
]
```

You can see that in this example, the Relational DB comes back with 2 rows per Object where the Date is either `StartTime` or `EndTime` (Row 1 vs. 2). Here it had to be combined as 2 columns from 2 rows. There are lots of examples like this, where tabular data needs to be somehow massaged into a JSON.

The solutions I see are

- On the JPA side, do some magic to massage/project results into custom
  objects, but this is very painful. Sometimes a Native SQL hack may be possible, other times not. This seems inconsistent and uncertain to me.
- Use manual JSON construction with tools like javax.json or GSON after getting "plain" JPA Entities back, but people tell me this is the wrong approach. But even if I go this route, I need 2 POJOs: one for getting custom results from JPA (because I won't be getting 'real' domain entities), and the other for actual final JSON representation.

How do people deal with this problem? Do they really tweak JPA/Hibernate, do they use manual population with GSON, or something else?

**Note** We are using PostgreSQL 10 as our DB.

Comment: It's not clear the concrete problem. What does it mean that the db comes back with 2 results? Show the code. Anyway, use the right tool for the purpose it's designed for: JPA for representing db objects and querying them, json libraries for converting an object to its json representation. BTW, why don't you use integers for representing rgba colors?

Comment: There are 2 Rows per Object Info entry in this case. Row 1 is StartTime (in the Date val) and Row 2 is EndTime (in the Date val).

Comment: Your tags says that you are using Spring. Spring MVC uses Jackson to auto generate JSON: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: If you are using NativeSQL with binding parameters then I don't think SQL injection is possible. http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2013/04/sessioncreatesqlquery.html also shows few more ways to make SQL Injection least possible.

Comment: @Simon Martinelli : Jackson will output the flat data grid as JSON, whereas in my case it needs to be reorganized to be hierarchical -- as I described StartTime/EndTime have to be combined. The question is, where to do this further processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html), *Mapped Entities* or  `@NamedNativeQuery` : to get the result exactly in the format you want and map it directly to the *JSON* object, your query should be something like this(depends on your RDBMS):

```
Select distinct id_char, color, date starTime,
(Select date from table t2 where t2.id_char=t1.id_cgar and t2.id_int=2) as endTime 
From table t1 where t1.id_int=1
```

You can also get the result as is and in your application layer convert it to the format you want using a simple *POJO* class.

Comment: So for Tip #2, you're saying it's OK to use a For-Loop to sequentially scan each row and build a POJO -- that is, for the same event, check for when it changes and then manually set the fields? Because I got a complaint that this is horrible and manual processing should be avoided.

Comment: No, I say Of course such this operations (using for-loops and processing the total result you get from DB in application layer) may have a negative effect on memory used for app and it's performance